# Is $A$ \ $B$ ~ $A$ true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

1) If $A$ is infinite and uncountable, and $B$ is finite or countable, is $A$ \ $B$ ~ $A$ true?

2) If $A$ is infinite uncountable and $B \subset A$ is finite or countable, is $A$ \ $B$ ~ $A$ true?

1)I assume it is true, because of the cardinality of the continuum?
2)Also true for the same reason?

Comment: by ~ do you mean equipotent ?

Comment: @zwim Yes, by ~ I mean equipotent.

Comment: Yes, yes and no.The cardinality of the continuum is not at all involved.

Comment: Assuming that is true isn't enough. You have to show it by using injections or something similar.

Comment: @Arthur That put aside, are those two statements true?

Comment: If you note $C=A\cap B$ then question 1) is same as 2) with $A\setminus C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) follows from 2), because in all cases $A \setminus B = A \setminus (A \cap B)$, and if $B$ is finite or countably infinite, so is $A \cap B$.

To prove 2), if $B$ is finite or countable, it is not all of $A$. So there exists $x \in A \setminus B$. Now you can apply the same argument to $A$ and $B \cup \{x\}$. Repeat. You will be able to find a countable subset $C$ of $A$, disjoint from $B$. Now: $A \setminus B = (A \setminus (B \cup C))\cup C$ and $A = (A \setminus(B\cup C)) \cup (B \cup C)$. The "outer" unions are disjoint unions in both cases.

Now compare the RHS of the two equations: The first term of the union is the same, and the second is a countably infinite set in both cases. There is a bijection between $C$ and $B\cup C$, and you can extend this with the identity map on $A\setminus(B\cup C)$ to get a bijection from $A\setminus B$ to $A$.

Comment: Since there is a bijection between $C$ and $B\cup C$ and from $A\setminus B$ to $A$, then we can say that both cases are true. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed both true. 
Assume that $A$ is uncountable, $B$ is countable, and $A - B$ is countable. Since the union of two countable sets is countable, then $(A - B) \cup B$ is countable. But $A \subset (A - B) \cup A;$ since a subset of a countable set is itself countable, we conclude that $A$ has to be countable. This contradiction proves that $A - B$ is uncountable.

Comment: The question wasn't just to prove that $A \setminus B$ is uncountable; it was to show it has the same cardinality as $A$, which is a stronger conclusion.

Comment: You're right, my bad.